# Problems with creating a stacked bar plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have 5 lists with 7 items each:

```
A=[0, 2, 0, 154018, 0, 0, 0]
B=[0, 22, 0, 153882, 0, 0, 0]
C=[0, 17, 0, 152901, 0, 0, 0]
D=[0, 14, 4, 154302, 0, 0, 0]
E=[0, 18, 8, 155052, 0, 0, 0]
```

I wold like to get a stacked bar plot according to each stations.
I tried with the below code but getting error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Stn1', A], ['Stn2', B], ['Stn3', C], 
    ['Stn4', D],['Stn5', E]],
    columns=['RU_26', 'RU_52', 'RU_106', 'RU_242', 
    'RU_484','RU_996','RU_2x996'])
```

Could someone help with this?

Comment: Maybe `df = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C, D, E], columns=['RU_26', 'RU_52', 'RU_106', 'RU_242', 'RU_484', 'RU_996', 'RU_2x996'], index=['A','B','C','D','E'])`  (or `['Stn1', 'Stn2', ...]` as index)? And plot with `df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)` or `df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`?  Having such huge numbers in the fourth column compared to the rest, makes a quite uninteresting plot.
`

Comment: `ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, logy=True)`